# how to store block after block processing back to full image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, block, addition

I have to perform a block-wise multiplication and store the block-wise result back to an image of full (same) dimension as of input image. I have developed some code but it's unable to store the individual block. The **input image** is of size **256*256**. Block of size **5*5**. The output image should be of 256*256. (i.e `Mul` is of size **(256*256)**).

```
clear all;
close all;
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
[row,col] = size(I);

block = 5;
Var = zeros(1:block,1:block);
 for i = 1:block:row-block
     for j= 1:block:col-block
         Var = I(i:i+block-1,j:j+block-1);
         Dem = reshape(1:25,[5 5])';
         Mul = Var.*Dem;
     end;
 end;
```

Comment: Could you use [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) for that?

Comment: yes i could use blockproc but i have to avoid using blockproc function in my code..So is there any logic do it without blockproc...Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to convert your image into cell containing 5 x 5 blocks. Since 256 does not divide by 5, you will have to do some adjustment. You can use [mat2tiles](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) that already does the adjustment. If you don't want to use external files, just check how they adjust for that. Anyway, you should be able to do it like this:

```
% convert image to tiles
C = mat2tiles(I, [5 5]);

% apply some function to each block. In example just zero all elements in blocks
C2 = cellfun(@(block) block.* 0, C, 'UniformOutput', 0);

% concatenate the results into new image
I2 = cell2mat(C2);
```

Comment: The combination of `mat2tiles` (or `mat2cell`), `cellfun` and `cell2mat` is one to remember. Don't bother with loops when you have these functions... just silly. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
clear all;

close all;

I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));

[row,col] = size(I);

block = 5;

Var = zeros(1:block,1:block);

% Initialize the output image

I2 = zeros(row,col);

Dem = reshape(1:25,[5 5])'; %'

 for i = 1:block:row-block

     for j= 1:block:col-block

         Var = I(i:i+block-1,j:j+block-1);

         Mul = Var.*Dem;

         % Remap the result to original size

         I2(i:i+block-1,j:j+block-1) = Mul;

     end;

 end;
```